# Jquery validation plugin - TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

My script throw errors:

> TypeError: jQuery.validator is undefined additional-methods.js:20
>   TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function index.php:115

Probably, I have mistake in jQuery code.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/additional-methods.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
            <form id="registerForm" method="post" action="logrej.php">
            <input name="login" type="text"/>
            <input name="nick" type="text"/>
            <input type="password" id="passw" name="password"/>
            <input type="password" name="retype" />
            <input type="submit" value="Zarejestruj!" />
            </form>
            <script>

                $("#registerForm").validate({
                    rules: {
                        login: {
                            required:true,
                            rangelenght: [4,20],
                            remote:"look.php"
                        },
                        nick : {
                            required:true,
                            rangelenght:[4,20],
                            remote:"look.php"
                        },
                        password: {
                            required:true,
                            rangelenght:[4.20]
                        },
                        retype: {
                            required:true,
                            equalTo:"#passw"
                        }
                    },
                    messages:{
                        login:{
                            required:"To pole jest wymagane!"
                        }
                    }
                })

            </script>
```

Comment: You have a typo on several lines: `rangelenght` should be `rangelength`.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You're not loading the validation plugin. You need:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Put this before the line that loads the additional methods.

Also, you should get the additional methods from the CDN as well, rather than jquery.bassistance.de.

Other errors:

```
[4.20]
```

should be

```
[4,20]
```

and

```
rangelenght:
```

should be:

```
rangelength:
```

Answer (score 11):

For me problem solved by changing http://ajax... into https://ajax... (add an S to http)

```
https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js
```

Answer (score 5):

Include [jquery.validate.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/jquery.validate.min.js) before `additional-methods.js`.

`$.validate()` method is defined there

Comment: Error in given link **Site Cant Be Reached**

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the JavaScript error your getting is probably being caused by

```
password: {
    required:true,
    rangelenght:[4.20]
},
```

As the `[4.20]` should be `[4,20]`, which i'd guess is throwing off the validation code in `additional-methods` hence giving the type error's you posted.

Edit: As others have noted in the below comments `rangelenght` is also misspelled & `jquery.validate.js` library appears to be missing (assuming its not compiled in to one of your other assets)

Comment: i don't think that would throw the typeerror that's occurring. but it likely is something that will cause issues later if not fixed.

Comment: he also has a typo in `rangelenght`.

Comment: I didn't initially clock the jquery.validate.js was missing, which thinking about is much more likely to be the problem (or at least the problem throwing those warnings, the rangelengtht spelling and [4.20] probably won't be helping anyway :p).

Answer (score 2):

You didn't include the base jQuery Validation library:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

Put that before the additional methods library. (BTW this is a hosted version, download your own if you want)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I am using jquery-validation as an npm module and the fix for me was to require the module at the start of my js file:

```
require('jquery-validation');
```

Answer (score 2):

for me, the problem was from `require('jquery-validation')` i added in the begging of that js file which Validate method used which is necessary as an **npm module**

unfortunately, when web pack compiles the js files, **they aren't in order**, so that the validate method is before defining it! and the error comes

so better to use another js file for compiling this library or use local validate method file or even using CDN but in all cases make sure you attached jquery before

Answer (score 1):

"validator.min.js"
You need to import this JS file after "jquery-3.4.1.min.js". For you version might change but this way has worked for me.

Step 1 : Your project link files or it might be CDN

Step 2 :

Put validator.min.js CDN link or project JS folder link.

That is all, hope it might helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and it was for a totally different reason.

I had been loading the libraries in the correct order but the problem was that I was wrapping `jQuery("#contact_form").validate();` inside `jQuery(document).ready(function () {});`.

When I placed it outside the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

If using VueJS, import all the js dependencies for jQuery extensions first, then import $ second...

```
import "../assets/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"
import "../assets/js/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"
import "../assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js"
import $ from "jquery";
```

You then need to use jquery from a javascript function called from a custom wrapper defined globally in the VueJS prototype method.

This safeguards use of jQuery and jQuery UI from fighting with VueJS.

```
Vue.prototype.$fValidateTag = function( sTag, rRules ) 
{
    return ValidateTag( sTag, rRules );
};

function ValidateTag( sTag, rRules )
{
    Var rTagT = $( sTag );
    return rParentTag.validate( sTag, rRules );
}
```