# How to trigger form validation on checkout button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Shopping cart contains html5 quantity validation as show in code below.
If clicked in Refresh button, browser shows error message and cancels submit.

If clicked in Checkout button, checkout url is invoked without validation.

How to trigger form validation if Chekcoutr button is pressed and cancel checkout button
press if form is invalid.

It is possible to use post request for Checkout button or refactor code to use multiple
submit buttons if this helps.

Bootstrap 3, jquery, ASP.NET MVC3, Mono are used.

```
<form action="/ShoppingCart/Update">
<input type="hidden" value='TOUR33' name='product' />
<input name="quantity" type="number" value="48000" max='1536' min="0" step="24" />
<input type='submit' value='Refresh' />
</form>
<a class="btn btn-success" href="/Checkout/Address">Checkout</a>
```

Comment: isn't it possible to keep `<input type="submit"/>` instead of `<a>`?

Comment: Andrus, which webserver do you use with Mono? Just curious.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao How to invoke `/Checkout/Address` if second submit button is used ? For this url there is no need to post form data. Form data can posted if this makes solution easier

Comment: just keep your submit button inside form and onclick of that write an event handler to handle valid and invalid `form`

Comment: code in question contains button in a element. This is not submit button. Submit button in code in form works OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should use js for this:

```
$('a.btn-success').click(function () {
   if ($("form").valid()) //trigger your form validation
   {
      return true;
   }
      return false;
 });
```

Comment: I tried but got javascript error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).valid is not a function` How to fix ?

Comment: @Andrus uh, you using server side validation? Or what kind of validation?

Comment: No. I'm using only code from this answer. For unknown reason $("form").valid() is not defined

Comment: I tried also `<form id='cart-form' ... >` and `$('#cart-form').valid()` but problem persists

Comment: I don't understand what kind of validation do you use. By default MVC has jquery.validate in project. You can read about your error [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21636977/1849444). You should just add scripts

Comment: I dont use MVC js includes. Standard html5 validation is used, without javascript. input type=number, max,min,step are validated automatically in Chrome without javascript